# How does pickling works in different scopes?

Tags: python, pickle

I'm trying to get a pickled list from a file but i just keep getting errors. Does unpickling the same object from the same file needs to be done inside every function or it's fine to unpickle it once?

Here's the last thing i tried:

```
import pickle, sys

def openFile(fileName, mode):
    """Open a file."""

    try:
        file =  open(fileName, mode)
    except IOError as e:
        print("Unable to open the file", fileName)
        print(e)
        input("Press the enter key to exit.")
        sys.exit()
    else:
        return file

def writeScore(file, score):
    """Write score to file."""

    try:
        highScores = pickle.load(file)
    except IOError as e:
        print("File doesn't exist.")
        print(e)
    except EOFError as e:
        print("File is empty.")
        print(e)
    else:
        highScores.append(score)
        highScores = highScores.sort()
        pickle.dump(highScores, file)

score_file = openFile("highScores.dat", "ab+")
writeScore(score_file, 1000)
score_file.close()

score_file = openFile("highScores.dat", "rb")
highScore = pickle.load(score_file)
print(highScore)
```

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: EOFError and IOError.

Comment: In the WriteScore function, you should first initialize the highScores list: `highScores = []` otherwise the `append` line will raise an error on the first time.

Comment: @Frodon isn't it initialized in `highScores = pickle.load(file)?`

Comment: @Jovito: not if an exception is raised

Comment: @Frodon Still getting the same error. I think that's not the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are tying to use `pickle.load()` on a file that is opened for appending, not for reading. Besides, your function `openFile()` does basically the same as `open()`.

My suggestion:

```
import pickle

def writeScore(file_, score):
    """Write score to file."""

    try:
        cache_file = open(file_, 'rb')
    except IOError:
        open(file_, 'a').close()
        cache_file = open(file_, 'rb')

    try:
        highScores = pickle.load(cache_file)
        highScores.append(score)
        highScores.sort()
    except EOFError:
        highScores = [score]
    finally:
        cache_file.close()

    writing_file = open(file_, 'wb')
    pickle.dump(highScores, writing_file)
    writing_file.close()

def displayScores(file_):
    """Display score from file."""

    cache_file = open(file_, 'rb')
    try:
        print pickle.load(cache_file)
    except (EOFError, IOError):
        print 'No scores to display.'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    scores_file = 'highScores.dat'

    writeScore(scores_file, 2000)
    displayScores(scores_file)

    writeScore(scores_file, 1000)
    displayScores(scores_file)
```

Or, even better, use `shelve`. You don't even need the functions then:

```
import shelve

def startDatabase(file_):
    """Creates a shelve from file."""

    return shelve.open(file_, writeback=True)

def writeScore(database, score):
    """Write score to file."""

    try:
        database['scores'].append(score)
        database['scores'].sort()
    except KeyError:
        database['scores'] = [score]

def displayScores(database):

    try:
        print database['scores']
    except KeyError:
        print 'No scores to display.'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    db = startDatabase('highScores.dat')

    displayScores(db)

    writeScore(db, 2000)
    displayScores(db)

    writeScore(db, 1000)
    displayScores(db)

    db.close()
```

Both yield the same output:

```
No scores to display.
[1000]
[1000, 2000]
```

Comment: Yep, the appending access to the file while loading the pickle was the problem.

Comment: Now i'm getting `TypeError: file must have 'read' and 'readline' attributes` :(

Comment: Can you detail the line of the exception and which solution you chose ?